# ios8 safari standalone web app crash on click select

Tags: web-applications, safari, ios8

How to reproduce the bug:
On iOS 8.1
enter http://greenti.cl/test.html with safari in iOS 8, save it to home screen. Enter via icon in homescreen, mess around with any of the selects. It Crashes

The real problem is occurring on a web app with meta "apple-mobile-web-app-capable", when launching the app from the home screen the browser interface isn't showed (normal behaviour). Clicking around a few times the select and the screen makes safari crash. This doesn't happen inside a normal safari window (only fullscreen windows made it crash).

Probably I should post something on safari for iOs developers forum, but I cant find where is that.

Comment: Hi, im having the same problem with iOS8.1. Did you find any solution or bug reported about this?

Comment: Hi, I reported this in Apple bug reporter 6 days ago and still have no answers, I'll keep you informed in case there is any news. By the way, people at jquery mobile claim that they solved it (or at least worked it around) see this link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7685, but since this is a native select bug, I would rather see the bug itself resolved, not a 3rd party workaround

Comment: Actually there is more people saying the workaround still doesn't work
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7685

People at Apple told me to post the debug log, but I haven't

Comment: Workaround doesn't work, workaround does not have the "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" meta tag...

Comment: It also seems to happen on input type="date"

Comment: The log shows the following error: : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController () should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

Answer (score 0):

We worked around this on our project (for now) by implementing select2 in place of normal select controls.

https://select2.github.io

I can confirm that tapping the select2 controls does not cause the crash, here is a fiddle: http://jsbin.com/wemadexiru/1/

I can also confirm that SelectBoxIt doesn't seem to work at least when set to use the native select control - as such the problem is the specific iOS8 native select.

It does have a wide range of options.

Obviously this isn't great, it is better than the JQuery Mobile non-native select control which seems quite unresponsive.